# how to get dictionary elements from text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to get dictionary elements from text file using python and i build this python code:

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

user_input = raw_input('Write group name: ')
data_file = open('data.txt', 'r')
d = data_file.read()
print d[user_input]
```

data.txt file:

```
group1 = {
    'jhon',
    'sam',
    'mees'
}

group2 = {
    '212332'
}

group3 = {
    'USA',
    'UK'
}
```

But i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py3", line 7, in <module>
    print d[user_input]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

How i can get the dictionary elements from `data.text` file?

Comment: The data in your file is actually a set and not a dict as per your question, you can copy a sample of your data verify it in ipython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d = data_file.read()` returns all the data in the file as a string.
One way you can assign the variables is using the `imp` module. This handles the `.txt` file as a python module:

```
import imp
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = imp.load_source('file', '', f)
```

Then you can retrieve the variables using the `.` operator:

```
>>> file.group1
{'sam', 'jhon', 'mees'}
>>> file.group2
{'212332'}
>>> file.group3
{'USA', 'UK'}
```

If you can rename your file you can change the extension to .py and simply import the file as a module:

```
import dataFile
```

Output:

```
>>> dataFile.group1
{'jhon', 'sam', 'mees'}
>>> dataFile.group2
{'212332'}
>>> dataFile.group3
{'USA', 'UK'}
```

Note that this means that you will have to comment out any non-python syntax from your file.

Comment: Great. it works but why i get the output with `set([])` set ?

Comment: when i print the `print dataFile.group2` i get the output like this `set(['212332'])`

Comment: You can convert set into data type of your  choice

Comment: @Farhan.K i need to take the `group` name from user input the access the data to get dic elements but i get error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'user_input'` code:  
 `import imp

 with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
  file = imp.load_source('file', '', f)
  user_input = raw_input('Group: ')
  xx = file.user_input
  for x in xx:
   print x`

Answer (score -1):

data.txt

```
{
    "group1": [
        " jhon",
        "sam",
        "mees"
    ],
    "group2": [
        "212332"
    ],
    "group3": [
        "USA",
        "UK"
    ]
}
```

code:

```
import json
data_file = open('data.txt', 'r')
d = json.loads(data_file.read().strip())
print d["group1"]
```

Comment: Thank you. the problem is i can't change the `data.txt` file because i get this data online from a website.